# Why is react displaying all my components at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import './css/hind.css';
import './css/splash.css';

import Feedback from './components/Feedback';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="add-100 dark-background">
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Feedback}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

And I would expect that at the url `/` I would see the first component, and at any other url, I would see the second.  The `NotFound` part is displaying how I would expect it too, but at `/`, I see the first component, then the second component displayed beneath it.  `NotFound` is definitely not in my `Feedback` file.  How do I use the router correctly so I only display the component I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your routes with `<Switch />`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './css/hind.css';
import './css/splash.css';

import Feedback from './components/Feedback';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="add-100 dark-background">
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Feedback}/>
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

What does `<Switch />` exactly do?

It renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

[source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Answer (score 1):

`path="*"` isn't actually supported in RRv4. Instead, a Route with no path property will always match. Combining the knowledge with the `Switch` component, you'll get the desired outcome. `Switch` will only render the first matching `Route`, so the idea is that if none of your other `Route`s match, then the last `Route` in your `Switch` component will render.

```
   <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Feedback}/>
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
    </Switch>
```